# Person Account creation AND Campaign Member activity in journey, based on email only

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sales-cloud

In MC, I have created a DE and CloudPage with Smart Capture form, to collect email address and some other fields. This CloudPage is the entry/trigger for a journey. What I want to do with the journey, is look up and update or create a Person Account in Service Cloud, but I also want to add that person to a (Sales Cloud) campaign. This last part is the problem.

I have got it to work once, but I found out that the email address was not being populated in the Person Account. Upon correcting this, it stopped working and has never worked since, no matter what I do.

The way the Person Account part is set up is through an Object Activity on 'Account (Person)'. I do a Find and Update, and match on email. When no record is found, I have one created, map last name to last name, email to email. This works, the account is created.

The neat way to work would be to do a Find and Update on the Campaign Member activity as well, but lookup fields are Campaign Member ID, Contact and Campaign, and Lead and Campaign, and in the journey, an account could just have been created but that does not technically give me the Contact (I think?).

The way I think it was working (I've tried so many things I'm a bit lost), is when I had chosen to go for a Create New action. Required fields are Campaign ID (which I have) and either Contact ID or Lead ID. I do not have those. But Account is optional, so I selected Account and selected SalesforceObjectID from the Journey Event Data (since this should be the id of the account that was just created in the previous step of the journey). When I then selected Contact ID, one option is to 'Assign to the Person in the Journey'. I selected this option, Saved, could not click Next, clicked another field, Canceled, could then click Next anyway, and that was it.

However, this does not work (anymore).

I also thought that if the Contact ID was really required, I could do an 'Account (Person)' Object activity first, have that create the Person Account, then in the next step do a 'Contact' Object activity, both with a lookup on Email. The second activity would then provide me with the SalesforceObjectID for the Contact as well, so I could use that in a Find and Update action in the Campaign Member activity.

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to add this newly created Account/Contact to a Campaign.

Please help!

Comment: Before you go down this road you should reconsider the current data flow setup as it generates duplicate records. One is created upon firing the journey based on the email address through smart capture. The second record will be the PersonAccount in the CRM. Best practice is to create a form that uses AMPSCRIPT to create or update a PersonAccount in CRM. This event can then be used to fire a journey or a Salesforce triggered email. By going this way Marketing Cloud receives only one record based the Salesforce record Id which will persist over the record lifetime.

Comment: @StephandePaly Thanks for your response! I agree that a form with Ampscript is probably the best solution technically. But ideally we want users that are not so technical to be able to set up a solution themselves. At the same time, the duplicate record will not be used for anything except creation of the CRM record. In CRM we generate a SubscriberKey, which is synced to Marketing Cloud and that record is the one we use for everything.

Comment: I understand this but I've seen this sort of setup before and it caused considerable issues. If you stay with this approach do not forget to implement a process that deletes the redundant records to avoid inflating your contact count. Salesforce enforces limits on those and this might become costly.

Comment: @StephandePaly Good point. That contact is of course counted as soon as it goes through a journey, which it does to create the Account in CRM. We're far from near our contact limit, but I'll definitely keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use for "Contact ID" the option: "Assign to the Person in the Journey".

This should be an option if you are using "Object Activity" for Account (Person) to: Create or Find and Update.

In my screenshots below, I am using "Create".

**Required Fields**

[image: Required Fields] **Select Assign to the Person in the Journe**y

[image: Assign to Person in Journey]